# PHP Warning: odbc_connect(): The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application,

Tags: php, iis, odbc, wamp

i was trying to connect odbc32 connection using `odbc_connect` from IIS using PHP windows 64 bit. My odbc driver is 32 bit and the IIS server or windows i am using is 64 bit which is causing the following issue .If anyone knows how to resolve it , please help me
Error:

> PHP Warning:  odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application,

> PHP Warning:  odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application,

Comment: 32 bit and 64 bit things don't work together. So, either you configure your IIS site on IIS to use a 32 bit enabled application pool, or you find the 64 bit ODBC driver.

Comment: The reason why you can normally run 32-bit applications in 64-bit operating systems is because these OSs have a compatibility layer explicitly crafted for that use case, but they're different architectures. PHP does not have any compatibility layer to run drivers from a different architecture.

Comment: The error you encounter indicates an architecture mismatch between the ODBC driver and the PHP runtime. To resolve this issue, you need to make sure that the architectures match.

Answer (score 0):

The error you encounter indicates an architecture mismatch between the ODBC driver and the PHP application. You have a 32-bit ODBC driver, but your PHP is running on a 64-bit server. To resolve this issue, you have the following options:

1. Ideally, you should use a 64-bit version of the ODBC driver that matches the architecture of your PHP application and server.
2. If you are unable to obtain the 64-bit ODBC driver, you can install the 32-bit version of PHP on your server. By default, IIS application pool runs in 64-bit mode. To run 32-bit applications, you may need to configure IIS to enable 32-bit applications:

- Open IIS Manager.
- In the Connections pane, select the application pool used by the PHP application.
- Click "Advanced Settings" in the right pane.
- Set the "Enable 32-Bit Applications" option to "True."